# Encrypting and Decrypting a user input string

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to write a program that will encrypt and decrypt a `String` that is input by the user. My code works but isn't generating a key that changes each time I run the program. No matter what I type, I get the same result. Any ideas what I could do to change this?

```
package SimpleCryptHandler;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleCryptHandler {

    private Key symKey;
    private Cipher cipher; 

    public SimpleCryptHandler(String algorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {               
        symKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm).generateKey();     
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String toEncrypt) 
            throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, symKey);
        byte[] inputBytes = toEncrypt.getBytes();
        return cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
    }

    public String decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt) 
            throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, symKey);
        byte[] decrypt = cipher.doFinal(toDecrypt);
        String decrypted = new String(decrypt);
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String encrypttype;

        System.out.println("What encrytion type would you like to use? (AES, Blowfish, DES, DESede, RC2)");
            encrypttype = input.nextLine();

        String algorithm = encrypttype;   //successfully tested with AES, Blowfish, DES, DESede, RC2
        SimpleCryptHandler cryptHandler = new SimpleCryptHandler(algorithm);

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);
        String pw;

        System.out.println("What would you like to encrypt?");
            pw = input2.nextLine();

        String input1 = pw;

        //Encryption
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cryptHandler.encrypt(input1);
        System.out.println(encrypttype + " Encrypted result of " + pw + ": " + encryptedBytes);

        //Decryption
        String decryptedStr = cryptHandler.decrypt(encryptedBytes);
        System.out.println("Decrypted result of: " + decryptedStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing an important step of initializing your key generator based on the algorithm.  See the [Java Docs on KeyGenerator init methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html#init(int)).

Your constructor would be modified to read:

```
keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
keyGen.init(..); // your choice as to which one works best for your needs
symKey = keyGen.generateKey();
```